# std::thread in MacPorts gcc4.5

Tags: g++, c++11, macports

I'm trying to compile some software I've been writing in Linux that uses some fancy new C++0x features on my Mac. I used MacPorts to install the gcc45 package, which gave me /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5, however this compiler doesn't want to compile anything in `<thread>`. Eg I try to compile:

```
//test.cpp
#include <thread>

int main()
{
std::thread x;
return 0;
}
```

and get:

```
bash-3.2$ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -std=c++0x test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:5:2: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
test.cpp:5:14: error: expected ';' before 'x'
```

A quick look in /opt/local/include/gcc45/c++/thread shows that the std::thread class is defined, but is guarded by the following:

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1)
```

Again, this works perfectly on my Ubuntu machine, so what's the proper way to enable the c++0x `<thread>` library under the MacPorts version of g++ 4.5 (g++-mp-4.5)? Failing that, is there anything I need to know (configure flags, etc.) before I go about compiling gcc 4.5 myself?

**Update:**
It doesn't look like the SO community knows much about this, so maybe it's time to go a little closer to the developers. Does anyone know of an official mailing list I could  forward this question to? Are there any etiquette tips to help me get an answer?

**Update 2:**
I asked SO for another temporary solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636651/substituting-boost-for-c0x-library-features), and so I'm now just substituting the boost::thread libraries for the std ones. Unfortunately, there is no boost::future so this isn't quite a full solution yet. Any help would still be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: I tried the fink version as well - no dice.

Comment: Update2: I've also tried the version of 4.6 compiled from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/index.php - also no dice.

Comment: Maybe you could try compiling with -pthread. Failing that, I haven't even the slightest idea.

Comment: Yup, already tried that. Thanks though!

Comment: Does using the keyword decltype cause an error?  This can be used to determine if C++0x support is actually compiled in.

Comment: decltype works just fine. All of the new core language features are there and working great, it's just the new threading part of the standard library that doesn't compile.

Comment: I think you need to link to pthreads: `-lpthread`. Most probably it is a bug, because GCC should link the standard libraries automatically!

Comment: @AraK - I tried that with no success. Thanks though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually `<thread>` library doesn't work under Mac OS X because pthreads here don't have some functions with timeouts (e.g. pthread_mutex_timedlock()). Availability of this functions have to be [checked](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Unix-porting/2008/Jan/msg00014.html) using `_POSIX_TIMEOUTS` macro but it's defined to `-1` in Mac OS X 10.4, 10.5 and 10.6 (I don't know what's about 10.7) and this functions are really absent in `pthread.h`.

The `_POSIX_TIMEOUTS` macro is checked during the configuration of libstdc++. If the check ends successfully `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` macro becomes defined. And `<thread>` contents become available with `-std=c++0x`.

libstdc++ really needs `_POSIX_TIMEOUTS` e.g. in `std::timed_mutex` class implementation (see `<mutex>` header).

To summarize, I think that `<thread>` would become available on Mac OS X when GCC's gthreads or libstdc++ will implement pthread_mutex_timedlock() (and others) emulation or when this functions will be implemented in Mac OS X.

Or maybe there would be a way in the future C++ standard to query for language features (e.g. this timed functions and classes) and it will be possible to build libstdc++ with this features disabled. However I'm not very familiar with the future standard and have doubts about that feature.

Answer (score 5):

**Update** - gcc4.7 now allows compilation of  on OS X: [See here](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/02/20/living-on-the-edge-building-gcc-4-7-on-mac-osx-lion/)

Comment: Exactly; MacPorts gcc 4.7.0 compiles your code with only `-std=c++0x` needed. It would be good to pop-up this update, so that other MacOS users get it working quickly.