# Substituting Boost for C++0x Library Features

Tags: c++, macos, boost, c++11

I'm working on a library that makes heavy use of the latest C++0x language and library features.  I'm mainly developing in Linux with gcc4.6, but would like to test in OS X (because Apple makes excellent profiling tools). Unfortunately all versions of libstdc++ that ship with any gcc4.6 for OS X I've found have their `<thread>` features disabled (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456602/stdthread-in-macports-gcc4-5) for my question on SO on how to get this fixed).

In the  meantime, does anyone have any ideas for a minimally invasive (for my library) way I can substitute boost's thread library for the standard one? I'd rather not resort to sed because I'm sharing this project over SVN and would like to check in my changes without forcing everyone else to switch to boost::thread, boost::mutex, etc as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a standard complaint code because you're not allowed to change the inside of namespace std, but it should work on most compilers:

```
#include <boost/your_headers.hpp>
namespace std {
    using boost::thread;
    using boost::mutex;
    // ...
}
```

the remaining code is unchanged.

Comment: An alternative approach might be namespace cxx0x = std; or namespace cxx0x = boost;. This avoids mucking about with std. You could also do namespace cxx0x { using std::mutex; } vs. namespace cxx0x { using boost::mutex; }

Comment: @Logan: sorry, but how does it help? what it does that the above code doesn't?

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! I'll test when I get to my work machine and accept your answer in a bit.

Comment: it just avoids reopening std which is technically a no-no.