# g++4.6 std::thread error on Mac OS-X 10.5

Tags: multithreading, macos, gcc, g++, macports

I was trying to test thread library of gcc4.6 on mac OS-X 10.5. 
I successfully compiled and installed gcc4.6 by macports. 
But the simplest concurrent hello world program failed. The code is like:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <thread>  

void sayhello() {std::cout << "Hello\n";}  
int main(){  
  std::thread t(sayhello);
  t.join();
}
```

I tried to compile and used `g++ -Wall -std=c++0x test.cpp`
I got the error:

`'thread' is not a member of 'std'`

Any idea what cause the problem and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: I am interested in this as well; from what I can tell the modifications made by Apple to 'their' 4.2 compiler are not available/being used by MacPorts (or anyone else) when building later versions.  If anyone knows different, I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, pthreads implementation as of OSX 10.6.8 lacks some required features for C++0x threads. During configure, gcc detects this and disable support for them. More details at [std::thread in MacPorts gcc4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456602/stdthread-in-macports-gcc4-5)