# Is std::promise broken on my machine (using g++-mp)?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, future

Is this code valid, or is my compiler broken?

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "doing the test" << std::endl;
   std::promise<bool> mypromise;
   std::future<bool> myfuture = mypromise.get_future();
   mypromise.set_value(true);
   bool result = myfuture.get();
   std::cout << "success, result is " << result << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out
doing the test
Segmentation fault: 11
$
```

I'm using g++-mp-4.8, which is the gcc 4.8 from macports.

Am I going insane?

Comment: Well, it crashes in Ideone as well: http://ideone.com/wNsr1h .  I don't know these libraries very well, but my guess is that this is probably not the right way to use them.

Comment: No segfault on Linux/g++-4.7.2, but `std::system_error` is thrown instead.

Comment: It works fine on stacked-crooked.com as well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=df733168554395fe0d5e28982f5b4899-61c3814520a8d4318f681038dc4b4da7

Comment: On a local GCC 4.8, I am only able to get this to work when adding the `-pthread` command line option (which is generally required when doing anything related to `std::thread`, probably including `std::future` and `std::promise` as well).

Comment: Succress on VS2012 with default flags.

Comment: I tried adding -lpthread, and it still didn't work. It sure is odd that we're getting mixed results! Should I report this as a bug to the people who made gcc?

Comment: @Verdagon I am not sure if it makes a difference in this case, but the option should actually be `-pthread`, not just the linker option `-lpthread`. (On my GCC, which is not `g++-mp`, it works with `-lpthread`, too, though.)

Comment: I tried both -pthread and -lpthread, no changes.

Comment: Without `-pthread`, I get exceptions or crashes on `mypromise.set_value(true)` in both gcc 4.7.2 and gcc 4.8 on [stacked crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).  So my guess is your code is correct, you just don't have the threading library linked properly -- maybe the mac port threading library is busted, or maybe arguments work different, or maybe you aren't running what you think you are running.

Comment: But threading otherwise works on my program, even mutexes and conditions and whatnot. Also, the link you gave has a more recent answer saying that it should work as of 4.7...

Comment: @Verdagon In that case, it's probably really a bug in the compiler (or in how it was built). As far as I can tell, your code is correct. (Btw the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456602/stdthread-in-macports-gcc4-5) originally given by Jesse, and the further pages linked from there, seem to indicate that `-pthread` is not actually required on Mac.)

Comment: Alright cool. I'll find a way to report this as a bug!

Comment: On LiveWorkspace it works fine: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1x07zw$0

Comment: Try running `otool -L ./a.out` to make sure you're using the `libstdc++.dylib` from GCC 4.8 and not the much older system library

Comment: Indeed I'm using libstdc++.6.dylib (does that .6 make a difference?)

$ otool -L ./a.out
./a.out:
 /opt/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.18.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
 /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
$

Ideas?

Comment: "std::promise broken" :) There ought be a badge for witty titles.

Comment: I have the same problem with the MacPort GCC versions... Bad.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic linker may be linking your program to an old version of `libstdc++`,  the one in `/opt/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`

Since you're compiling with GCC 4.8 you need to use the new `libstdc++` that comes with GCC 4.8, which is probably `/opt/local/lib/gcc48/libstdc++.6.dylib`

You should check whether `/opt/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib` is the library that comes with GCC 4.8 and use the right one if it isn't.

You can control that in various ways, the simplest (but not necessarily the best) would be to run:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/gcc48/
./a.out
```

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic for other info (which is not specific to Mac OS X)

Comment: No luck =\ Indeed I have that folder, but doing that export line before the ./a.out resulted in no change. I also tried that line before the g++-mp-4.8 call, but no change there either...

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles and runs fine for me in Xcode. The output is

doing the test
success, result is 1

The compiler is Apple LLVM 4.2

Thus, I suggest you have a compiler configuration problem

Comment: You got c++11 to work in xcode? The reason I'm using g++-mp-4.8 is that I couldn't get that to work. Can you point me to where you learned how to configure xcode for c++11?

Comment: OK - first off I'm using XCode 4.6. I can't remember exactly where I found the instructions, but go to Build Options->Compiler: Set it to Apple LLVM compiler 4.2. Then go to C++ Language Dialect and select GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]

Comment: Apparently the answer is wrong. GCC 4.2 (Apple or other flavours does not support future/async). The new Xcode should be able to compile the code, using clang and libc++.

Comment: Hi Yongwei - could you elaborate on what is 'wrong'? Is it my description of how I got c++11 configured in xcode? The OP has not marked any response as correct - so I'm not sure what you mean as THE answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a MacPorts bug. There are already bug reports on MacPorts. You can follow there:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/38814 (main issue)
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/38833 (my report, currently marked as duplicate of #38814)

Answer (score 0):

confirmed: your code produces the same problem here:

compiler: `g++ -v` gives

```
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12
```

> Configured with: ../gcc-4.8-20130328/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc48 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc48 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.8 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.8 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc48 4.8-20130328_0'

```
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.8.1 20130328 (prerelease) (MacPorts gcc48 4.8-20130328_0)
```

running it in gdb gives:

```
doing the test

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100081c30 in __once_proxy ()
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007fff8872fff0 in pthread_once ()
(gdb) up
#2  0x0000000100000fd2 in __gthread_once ()
(gdb) up
#3  0x00000001000020c9 in _ZSt9call_onceIMNSt13__future_base11_State_baseEFvRSt8functionIFSt10unique_ptrINS0_12_Result_baseENS4_8_DeleterEEvEERbEIKPS1_St17reference_wrapperIS8_ESF_IbEEEvRSt9once_flagOT_DpOT0_ ()
(gdb) up
#4  0x0000000100001886 in std::__future_base::_State_base::_M_set_result ()
(gdb) up
#5  0x00000001000025ef in std::promise<bool>::set_value ()
(gdb) up
#6  0x000000010000119f in main ()
```

so this seems some bug in libstdc++. Btw, using clang 3.2 (homebrew), this compiles & runs fine (`result is 1`). Perhaps you should file a bug report with bugzilla ...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to use GCC, the latest version of the Apple compiler works. Be sure you install the latest Xcode and also the "command line tools" from within Xcode.

The command line should be:

`clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -pthread test.cpp`